# column/row span for html table

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to put my controls in attached html structure. 
Can anyone give me quick code for it? [image: Table]

Comment: Using what html elements? `table`, `div`, something else? What defines the dimensions of each?

Comment: looking at the title, i guess he needs a `table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your image there are 2 rows and 4 columns in the table.

1. First row has 3 cells, first with colspan 2 and other without any span
2. Second row has 4 cells without any span.

You can get this Table structure by using this code.

---

```
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nsp;</td>
    <td>&nsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nsp;</td>
    <td>&nsp;</td>
    <td>&nsp;</td>
    <td>&nsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"> column 1 </td>
    <td> column 2 </td>
    <td> column 3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> column 1 </td>
    <td> column 2 </td>
    <td> column 3 </td>
    <td> column 4 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```